# usort works fine with WAMP, gives syntax error on remote server.

Tags: php, function, sorting

I'm trying to run PHP's usort function to sort an array of files by the time they were created. Here is the code:

```
$files = array(); 

$files = glob('./posts/*.txt');
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
      return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b); //lambda sort
});
```

usort of course references an array and applies a user defined callback function to sort those elements.

When I run this on my WAMP server and redirect to localhost it works perfectly, but when i tried to upload the file to my remote server (HostGator) it gave the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home1/joshua1/public_html/blog.php
```

Both my WAMP server and my HostGator remote server are running a version of PHP 5. 
I'm rather new to PHP, could somebody point me in the right direction? (I'm assuming it's a configuration mismatch, but i'm not positive)

Comment: The [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) docs specify it must be of type [`callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). The Callbacks docs there mention passing the function name as a string. It also mentions a change in PHP 5.2.3, which seems unrelated to your issue but implies there might be other differences in `usort()` even between minor versions of PHP5. You might try defining your callback function separately and with a name, then passing a string of said function name as the second arg to `usort()`. I may be off here, not a PHP expert, but it's worth a shot IMHO.

Comment: yeah I saw that in the documentation. I don't know why it would make a difference but i'll give it a shot.

Comment: Yup that worked, apparently anonymous functions aren't supported in the version of php installed on my sever.. thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah PHP, how I loathe thee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out anonymous functions aren't supported in the version of PHP installed on my server. This works:

```
$files = array(); 

function filesort($a, $b) { 
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b); 
}

$files = glob('./posts/*.txt');
usort($files, "filesort");
```

Comment: You are, of course, encouraged to mark the answer as accepted, since it solved your problem.